# How do I define the default behaviors of a bot in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, botframework

Consider the following is the dialog.

```
bot.dialog('/beer', [
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.number(session, "How many mugs would you like?");
    },
    function (session, results) {
        if (results.response && results.response.entity != '(quit)') {
            // Launch demo dialog
            session.endDialog("Beer" + (results.response == 1 ? " is on the" : "s are on their") + " way, enjoy!");
        } else {
            // Exit the menu
            session.endDialog("Goodbye, See you later..");
        }
    }
]);
```

When this gets prompted to the user if the user types in the text (e.g. 'Test') instead of a valid number, the bot gives the response like **default_number**.

The same default error message for number is **default_number**, choice is **default_choice**, text **default_error**, etc.. I have tried different ways to figure out how to take control over it and define the default behavior something like bot says **"I did not recognize it, please try again"** instead of giving the error, which doesn't make any sense to user.

Can anyone put some light on this?

Reference link
https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/prompts/#promptsnumber

Answer (score 4):

*(Better Answers are always welcomed.)*

Finally after searching a lot found the following stuff.

In the emulator by default it handles the error messages & show something

> **"Oops. Something went wrong and we need to start over."**

or

> **"I didn't understand. "**.

But on Direct Line APIs/other channel like Skype. The actual bot response is getting displayed which is like "**default_error**", "**default_choice**", etc..

To change the default error messages, we can simply add a file called **'BotBuilder.json'** inside the folder

```
BotProject/locale/<languageCode>/BotBuilder.json
```

So the file contains the text message which override the default error as follows:

```
{
    "default_error": "I did not recognize it. Please try again."
}
```

---

**Update**: Hope this is all the possible list to override.

```
{
    "default_text": "I didn't understand. Please try again.",
    "default_number": "I didn't recognize that as a number. Please enter a number.",
    "default_confirm": "I didn't understand. Please answer 'yes' or 'no'.",
    "default_choice": "I didn't understand. Please choose an option from the list.",
    "default_time": "I didn't recognize the time you entered. Please try again using a format of (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS).",
    "default_file": "I didn't receive a file. Please try again.",
    "default_error": "Oops. Something went wrong and we need to start over."
}
```